# Database Table Schema and Aggregate Roots

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, database-design

Applicaiton is single user, 1-tier(1 pc), database SqlCE. DataService layer will be (I think) : Repository returning domain objects and quering database with LinqToSql (dbml). There are obviously a lot more columns, this is simplified view.

LogTime in separate table: http://i53.tinypic.com/9h8cb4.png

LogTime in ItemTimeLog table (as Time): http://i51.tinypic.com/4dvv4.png

[alt text http://i53.tinypic.com/9h8cb4.png](http://i53.tinypic.com/9h8cb4.png)

*This is my first attempt of creating a >2 tables database. I think the table schema makes sense, but I need some reassurance or critics. Because the table relations looks quite scary to be honest. I'm hoping you could;*

- Look at the table schema and respond if there are clear signs of troubles or errors that you spot right away..  And if you have time,
- Look at Program Summary/Questions, and see if the table layout makes makes sense to those points.

Please be brutal, I will try to defend :)

**Program summary:**

**a)** A set of categories, each having a set of strategies (1:m)

**b)** Each day a number of items will be produced. And each strategy MAY reference it.
 (So there can be 50 items, and a strategy may reference 23 of them)

**c)** An item can be referenced by more than one strategy. So I think it's an m:m relation.

**d)** Status values will be logged at fixed time-fractions through the day, for: 
-       .... each Strategy.....each StrategyItem....each item

**e)** An action on an item may be executed by a strategy that reference it. 
- This is logged as ItemAction (Could have called it StrategyItemAction)

**User Requsts**

b) -> e) described the  ***main activity mode***  of the program. To work with only  ***today's DayLog*** , for each category. ***2nd priority*** activity is ***retrieval of history***, which typically will be From all categories, from day x to day y; Get all StrategyDailyLog.

**Questions**

1. First, does the overall layout look sound? I'm worried to see that there are so many relationships in all directions, connecting everything. Is this normal, or does it look like trouble?
2. StrategyItem is made to represent an m:m relationship. Is it correct as I noted 1:m / 1:1 (marked red) ?
3. StrategyItemTimeLog and ItemTimeLog; Logs values that both need to be retrieved together, when retreiving a StrategyItem. Reason I separated is that the first one is strategy-specific, and several strategies can reference same item. So I thought not to duplicate those values that are not dependent no strategy, but only on the item. Hence I also dragged out the LogTime, as it seems to be the only parameter to unite the logs. But this all looks quite disturbing with those 3 tables. Does it make sense at all? Or you have suggestion?
4. Pink circles shows my vague attempt of Aggregate Root Paths. I've been thinking in terms of "what entity is responsible for delete". Though I'm unsure about the actual root. I think it's Category. Does it make sense related to ***User Requests*** described above?

---

**EDIT1:**
*(Updated schema, showing typical number of hierarchy items for the first few relations, for 365 days, and additional explanations)*

**1:1 relation:** Sorry. I made a mistake. The StrategyDailyLog should be 1:m. See updated schema. It is one per Strategy, per day.

**DayLog / StrategyDailyLog:** I’ve been pondering over wether DayLog shall be a part of the hierarchy like this or not. The purpose of the DayLog table is to hold “sum values” derived from all the StrategyDailyLog tables for the same day. Like performance values for this day. It also holds the date value. Which allows me to omit a date value in the StrategyDailyLog (Which I feel would kind of be a duplicate modeling of the date-field), but instead the reference to DayLog exist to “find” the date.  I’m not sure if this is an abuse/misconception of normalization.

**Null value:**  I haden’t thought about this. I believe I found 2, as now marked in StrategyDailyLog and ItemAction. They can not be null on creation, but they can be set to null if one need to delete either a Strategy, or a StrategyItem. That should not require a delete of the StrategyDailyLog and the ItemAction. Hence they can be set to null.

**All Id –columns:** My idea was to have ID (autogenerated Integer) as PK for all my tables. I believed that also would be sufficient as candidate key. Is this not a proper way to make PKs?  It’s the only way any table of mine can be identified. I asked a question before if that was ok, maybe I misunderstood, but thought that was a good approach.

**m:m relation:** This is what I have attempted to do: StrategyItem is the m:m table of StrategyDailyLog / DailyItem.

Comment: Why `DailyItem` -- as opposed to `Item`?

Comment: That was just to indicate that the Item is unique for each day. Similar Item for other day will be a unique row. Maybe not a good naming, but that was my reason.

Comment: Also the DailyItems exist regardless of the strategies. Each strategy can however chose to "plug into" an Item, by the m:m table StrategyItem..  Does that make sense?

Comment: I renamed it to "Item". I agree it was confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Here is me being brutal. I do not understand the model.
So instead of trying to comment on that so much, here are some thoughts that came to my mind when I looked at it.

I think you should have look at your 1:1 relationships (all of them). Why is DayLog and StrategyDailyLog separated in two tables? Probably because you will always have at least one DayLog item but not all DayLog items have a StrategyDailyLog item. If that is the case you can have a StrategyID FK in DayLog table with allow nulls option.

It would help to understand the model if you could show which fields are required and which fields accept null as a value.

All your tables have its own id column. That can be quite confusing when doing 1:1 relations and m:m relations. For a 1:1 relation, usually the relation between the two tables is made on the primary key in both tables. If you do not do that you have to create a candidate key on the foreign key column. In your case that means that StrategyDailyLog should have a candidate key on DayLogID.

A m:m relation between two tables is usually solved by adding a new table in between, with the primary keys from both tables. Those fields together is the primary key for the table in the middle.
Lets say for example that you should have a m:m relationship between Category and Strategy. You should then create a table called CategoryStrategy with two fields CategoryID and StrategyID that together is the primary key for table CategoryStrategy.

I hope my comments makes sense and that they are useful to you.

**EDIT 2011-01-17**

I do not think that you should have as a principle to use a IDENTITY column as primary key in all tables. A m:m relation does not need it so you should not do it. I also think that you have misunderstood what I meant with a candidate key. A candidate key is a key that could have been used as the primary key. In MS SQL Server you define a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT for your candidate key.
Ex: Table StrategyItem have id as PK but the combination of StrategyID and DailyItemID is the candidate key. Better would be to remove id and use StrategyID+DailyItemID as PK.

Below is the schema that I would have built with your description. I might have missed something important because I do not know everything about what you want to do.
You should not think so much about query performance and building aggregates when designing the schema. That can be handled by creating indexes on columns and using sum, count and group by in your queries. An index on column Created in the model below would be necessary for your queries on a date or date interval. In MS SQL Server there is something called  the clustered index. Default the PK of a table is the clustered index but in this case I would make the index on Created column the clustered index.

A Category has 0,1 or more Strategy.
LogItem have on Category and optionally one Strategy
LogItem.Created holds date and time.

[image]

Comment: :) Thanks!  You may have pointed to some misconceptions in my understanding. But I'm not 100% sure. Please see EDIT1 above where I respond to your points.  cheers

Comment: @bretddog Added some more stuff to answer