# Database normalization and duplicate values

Tags: c#, sql, mysql, sql-server, database

Consider a Parent / Child / GrandChild  structure in a database table schema, or even a deeper hierarchy. These being in the same aggregate. One table DAYS keeps a single row per day, and has a "Date" field. This is the root table, or maybe a child of the root. No row can ever be deleted in this table.

In this case, however complex my table schema looks like, however far away in the hierarchy any other table is, **is there any reason why any other table would hold a Date value?  Can't it instead just have a FK to the DAYS table.**

I obviously assume that the creation of these date fields happen not before such datefield exist in the DAYS table.

I'm now thinking just about the date part to be relevant, not the time part. Not sure if all databases can store these individually. That's maybe relevant, but not really the main focus of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is frequently done in non-relational dimensionally modeled data warehouses - a date dimension table gives a number of feature which allow you to easily aggregate quickly on facts by additional columns stored in the date dimension, like year, quarter, etc.  It often contains dozens of columns which mean that you are not required to apply code to determine if it's a work day or a holiday or the day name of the week or anything else.  It's a classic space/time tradeoff and pays off well for data in a limited date range of a couple hundred years like you might see in a bank or business.  It is not really feasible for an arbitrary date range of many hundreds of years.

Note that some RDBMS systems have a more efficient date-only data type (SQL Server has one as of SQL Server 2008).  Similarly, often the PK in the date dimension is an integer in natural form of YYYYMMDD, which takes considerably less space than a regular datetime column.

There can be advantages to such a scheme.  You can have special reserved dimensions for certain dates with very specific semantics - -1 - unknown, -2 - invalid, -3 - waiting etc., while a regular date column just has ability to store a valid date or NULL.

I don't think joins are necessarily an argument against this for performance reasons, after all, you will likely have a very efficient indexing on this and it's going to result in index seeks.  On the other hand, a typical date dimension table has many columns, and in an OLTP scenario, you rarely need much of that.

If your application does heavy date analysis and reporting, I would consider a date dimension (or call it a lookup table, since you are likely not in a dimensional/data warehouse scenario).  Otherwise, I would not - most people would not be comfortable with this, and exposure to dimensional modeling techniques is not common amongst many (most?) OLTP practitioners, and they will not see the benefits, although there are clearly many.

I see in your reply to another question that you need to log data on a minute basis.  Often, an orthogonal time dimension is set up in a similar way.  It is usually also very efficient, with a natural key of the form HHMMSS or just HHMM.  This makes it much easier to perform range analysis across days, and with a time table, in particular buckets, especially where such buckets may need to be identified with additional attributes.

Again, SQL Server 2008 has a separate time-only data type, so simply having DATE and TIME split in your table may be more than sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your table can reference the DAYS table, but I would not ask for a reason to store just the Date value. I would ask for a reason to introduce this new relation, which will slow down your database and has - at least based on your description - no additional value. Think about introducing a table with all possible integers and referencing that one from all other tables. It is possible, but makes not much sense. Your example is quite close to that.

Comment: I see.. Maybe I generalized a bit too much. The program I'm working on deals with logging of data continously through the day, and I will always make requests to get "this and that" from day x. Or from day x to day y. So I was not just thinking about storage, but I thought it was faster too look up based on such a reference. But if this is no good reason, it seems I need to introduce a date field in all my tables. Which seems a bit strange, but maybe it's not.

Comment: You are trying to take over the job of the database. Use an index on the date fields and you will get what you wanted to achieve with your date table. An possible optimization would be to transform the full date in an integer which represents a single day (since 01.01.1900 for example). But first have a look at your DB documentation. It might already have a datatype for such fields.

Comment: What do you mean by "use and index on the date fields"?  Currently I plan to use an Integer PK Identity field for all my tables, and hoped that would be a good solution.  I'm using SqlCE, so I guess I have only a datetime field.

Answer (score 1):

What is the business process you are trying to model? Why would you want to store data in this manner?

Take a look at [Designing Historical Tables](http://chaves-ca.wikidot.com/designing-historical-tables).

I wonder if perhaps concerns for data presentation are overriding the requirements for what you *actually need to store* in your database.

Don't try and create a model for time unnecessarily. Again this will depend on the business process you are trying to model and the type of database solution OLTP/OLAP that you are looking to implement.

For OLTP solutions you would typically look to record the *specific time* (datetime data type for example) that events actually occur, as opposed to modelling all possible time values and seeking to relate relevant times to events. You can then focus on reporting or presentation needs afterwards.

For OLAP solutions it is quite common to create a Date/Calendar Dimension in order to model time to support data analytics and reporting requirements.

Comment: Interesting, though not sure if this is overkill for my purpose. I need to log data on a minute-basis, every day. Data will never be changed (except deleted). And all my tables have integer Identity PKs (at least I thought that was ok solution). So I think I need only to concern about storage and data lookup efficiency.   It just feels logical to me to have a "DAYS" table as the root of such data. To easily drill down to specific dates. But this is my first database, so I can very easily be wrong :)

Comment: btw, my current model is shown here, if it's understandable I hope: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700391/database-table-schema-and-aggregate-roots

Comment: @bretddog: Thanks for the link to your schema design. Unfortunately I would need to understand the "business process", objects and events that you are trying to model in order to be able to interpret your schema.

Answer (score 0):

If using a foreign key you have to go lookup the real value in the other table.
You might be concerned with saving the space but the foreign key is still a couple of bytes plus you would need an index on the days table to make lookups faster